# Spring MVC LocaleChangeInterceptor annotation based doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, localization, internationalization

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        final CookieLocaleResolver ret = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        ret.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en_US"));
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ret.setBasename("classpath:lang");
        ret.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        final LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("language");

        final DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping ret = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
        ret.setInterceptors(new Object[] { interceptor });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The above is my annotation configuration. I've basically translated [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/) tutorial's XML.

Strangely it doesn't work when I go to `...?language=fr`.

However, the following does work (in `app-servlet.xml`) (notice here it's using `locale`):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Another important thing to note is that when I put breakpoints on the above methods, all of the three of them, every breakpoint does break, which implies that "someone" is reading the values.

So, why wouldn't my annotation based interceptor doesn't work?

Answer (score 13):

Extending config class by `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`  may help.
to add interceptor entry override

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

method.
also add bean entry for `LocaleChangeInterceptor`

```
@Bean 
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what swap says, you need to add:

```
@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
    return new CookieLocaleResolver();
}
```

The bean name is important. That's the way spring will resolve the correct locale resolver.

Alternatively you can return the SessionLocaleResolver.

If you do not add this you will get the following error:

```
Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The name of bean is the solution @Bean(name = "localeResolver")

Answer (score 5):

The full example of Spring MVC 4.1.4.RELEASE localization is posted.
Also you can use MKYong's [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/) (but unfortunately its config is based on XML) to solve the problems with project structure.

```
package com.pizza.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value = "com.pizza")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /* Resolvers and other MVC needs */

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


    /* Localization section is started */

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
        return new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ret = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        ret.setBasename("classpath:languages");
        ret.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return ret;
    }

}
```