# Using Locale in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use the `LocaleResolver` from Spring to change my page language when user wants. The initial language should be Portuguese, but it's not working as expected:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt-BR"));//StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en")

    return localeResolver;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior your expect and what you actually get? Please provide an MCVE that reflects this.

Comment: You can access the site in http://www.youplugy.com.br. The idea is, when it is accessed, it should be in Portuguese version. Is that helps?

Comment: I don't want to access your site, I want to see how you configured your application and a sample page. I also want you to explain what you expect, why you expect it, and what actually occurs.

Comment: This interceptor of code should change the language of my page, when it's accessed. It should be done by the code that I posted. What I expected is change the language of page, that starts with English and should be portuguese. I expected that because of what I set in the code above (localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt-BR"));), however, it's still initializing with English. I don't have problems to change the language after, just in the initial access. Please, let me know if you still need any sample page

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752710/spring-mvc-localechangeinterceptor-annotation-based-doesnt-work

Comment: The very minimal code you've posted works fine for me. Please post a complete and reproducible example that will demonstrate what you think should happen, why, and what actually happens.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean with "but it's not working as expected" but you use the Locale constructor the wrong way. First language and country are separated by an underscore not a minus and the single String argument constructor is for language only. So you have two valid options:

```
new Locale("pt", "BR")
```

or

```
StringUtils.parseLocaleString("pt_BR")
```