# Spring RequestMapping from Resources and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, property-placeholder

I'm trying to do a `RequestMapping` for URL from the `Resources` file to be variable according to the current `Locale`

I tried to use the `PlaceHolders` but i know it should load from `Properties` files . in addition to i have to load it as `Bean` during the run time thus it will load one time only with the default `Locale` so even if the changed the Locale , it will keep loading from the default `Locale` > `en_US`

Any Ideas ?

My Tries :

```
public class CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        setProperties(convertResourceBundleToProperties(ResourceBundle.getBundle("urls", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())));
        super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    }
}
```

and calling at in a `Bean` :

```
@Bean
public CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(){
    return new CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Resources `urls_ab.properties`:

```
url.controller1=test
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/${url.controller1}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String dd(ModelMap model){   
    return "__front_container";
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change locales during the request? That won't be possible because the placeholders are replaced during the applicationContext creation, so to refresh it with different values, you would need to refresh everything.

Comment: @dambros i want the URL `${url.controller1}` to be loaded from the proper resource according to the current locale , so in case if the locale is `en` and `url.controller1 = aa` so the `requestmap` automatically be /aa , and in case if the locale is `ab` and `url.controller1=test` the `requestmap` be `/test` and so on.

Comment: During the application start it is easy to achieve via profiles, but while it is running you wont be able to change it. Is that ok? If so I can show you some example

Comment: this is the problem , during the running i can't inject `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to replace the loaded resource file with the new file after changing the `locale` . i think i have to develop something like an internal proxy hmmmm

Comment: Yes, it won't work to refresh the values. That is not how the placeholders are supposed to work, even less supposed are the requestMapping with variable values. `http://localhost/englishUrl?lang=en` now if you want a different locale how can you call the new endpoint before it changed with something like `http://localhost/spanishUrl?lang=es`? This url doesn't exists yet.

Comment: yes, i'll try an idea , i'll load all URLs values for the supported locales in `Bean` , and will develop a filter to parse the request URL to compare the `URL` and matches them to their `controller` `method` according to the loaded Locale , i think i'll use `HTTPServeletRequest.getRequestDispatcher.forward` inside the `custom filter` to forward the request to the proper `controller`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109340/discussion-between-jason4ever-and-dambros).

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change to your properties files that back your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, you will need to 'refresh' your application for changes to take effect. If you use a ConfigurableApplicationContext as your context, then you may call refresh on your context. The challenge is that in a web application, you will depend on your web.xml and not directly on the context object so refreshing to load the new/updated properties would require an application restart...or going through many unnecessary hoops. Consider the below which is an example within a Spring Webflow application. The locale is updated via the use of an interceptor. :

```
public class MyLocaleChangeInterceptor extends org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor {
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    Locale locale = (Locale) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    if (locale != null) {
        try {
            response.setLocale(locale);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
    } else {
        response.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}
```

}

```
 /** https://gist.github.com/jkuipers/3537965 Spring LocaleResolver that uses cookies but falls back to the HTTP Session when cookies are disabled*/
public class MyCookieLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {
private SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
@Override
protected Locale determineDefaultLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return sessionLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(request);
}
@Override
public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {
    if (locale != null) {
        try {
            response.setLocale(locale);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            response.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
    } else {
        response.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    super.setLocale(request, response, locale);
    sessionLocaleResolver.setLocale(request, response, locale);
}
@Override
public void setDefaultLocale(Locale defaultLocale) {
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(defaultLocale);
}
```

}

```
<!--Then the XML:-->
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="MyLocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
</bean>
<!-- Saves a locale change using a cookie -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="MyCookieLocaleResolver" >
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>


<!--Then Spring-webflow specific XML settings:-->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="interceptors" >
        <list>
            <ref local="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

If using Spring MVC (without spring webflow), see here for a brilliant solution: [Spring MVC LocaleChangeInterceptor annotation based doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752710/spring-mvc-localechangeinterceptor-annotation-based-doesnt-work)

MyKong also provides a good solution: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/